# Capturing mouse events like click, pointer movement

Tags: linux, mouseevent, mouse

I am working on a project which requires capturing mouse and keyboard events. I found [logkeys](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys) project useful for the purpose of capturing keyboard events. I could not find the similar implementation/project for the mouse events. Can somebody please help me out?